# Selenium Python, i try to close a cookie button, but it ends clicking on the ad

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I tried to close a cookie button on whoscored.com, I located the button, however when the program clicks, it seems to click the ad behind the button, and it ends up opening a new page instead of closing the cookie button. Any idea of what I can do?

```
url='https://www.whoscored.com/Search/?t=Crystal+Palace'
browse=webdriver.Chrome()
browse.get(url)

time.sleep(4) 

cacheButton=browse.find_elements_by_xpath('//button')
cacheButton[1].click() #This is the "I ACCEPT" button.
```

Here is the html for the button:

```
<button class="qc-cmp-button" onclick="window.__cmpui(&quot;setAndSaveAllConsent&quot;,!0)"> I accept </button>
```

Would appreciate if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`() and following `xpath`.

```
WebDriverWait(browse,15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@class='qc-cmp-button' and contains(.,'I accept')]"))).click()
```

Add following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

---

**Code**:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url='https://www.whoscored.com/Search/?t=Crystal+Palace'
browse=webdriver.Chrome()
browse.get(url)
WebDriverWait(browse,15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@class='qc-cmp-button' and contains(.,'I accept')]"))).click()
```

**Browser sanpshot:**

[image]

**Update**:

```
cookie=btn=WebDriverWait(browse,15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//button[@class='qc-cmp-button' and contains(.,'I accept')]")))
browse.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", cookie)
```

Comment: I tried your code, however it seems like I have the same problem. It justs clicks the the ad in the back instead of the cookie blocker, and opens a new page. Do you have any idea why this happens or how to fix it? By the way I appreciate you taking time to help me.

Comment: @Aleksander : It should not happen.I am getting proper click and you can see snapshot after click.

Comment: @Aleksander : Just try with js to click.Let me know how this goes.I have updated with js click option as well.

Comment: Do you have any kind of adblock or something? I see I have ads beside the frontpage banner, but you do not.

Comment: @Aleksander : Nope.Try js click option.check updated section?